# How to change keyboardin telegram

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Welcome, " + msg.from.first_name + ". Choose a style and you'll be provided with a link to some nice musik ;)", {
        "reply_markup": {
            "keyboard": [["Jazz", "House"], ["Techno", "Electro"]]
        }
    });

});

var rand_electro = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * electro_collection.length);
}

var rand_house = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * house_collection.length);
}

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    var electro = "electro";
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(electro) === 0) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Here is your electro song " + msg.from.first_name);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, electro_collection[rand_electro()]);
    }
});


bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    var house = "house";
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(house) === 0) {
        console.log(count += 1);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Here is your house song ", {
            "reply_markup": {
                "keyboard": [["More house"], ["Back to choose style"]]
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Above is my telegram bot coded in js with node-telegram-api.

The first inline-keyboard (with 4 buttons) is ok, but when I want to change it into the one with 2 buttons only it never happens. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's albout console.log(count+=1) which should not stay there!